# Not able to call plugin function in angular js controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using http://idangero.us/swiper plugin. I have a button in the second slide. On click of that button, the slider should navigate to go to next slide.

My **html** file

```html
 <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2
            <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
   <script src="swiper.js"></script>
```

My **controller** file

```js
app.controller('tutorialController', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $state) {

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true
   
});

$scope.next =function(){
swiper.slideNext();
}

});
```

When I click on Next button, I am getting error as below:

```
TypeError: swiper.slideNext is not a function
    at ChildScope.$scope.next (tutorialController.js:10)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643), <anonymous>:4:203)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65429
    at ChildScope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16792)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16780)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2942)
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: have you included swiper js file in your HTML ?

Comment: yes, I have included swiper.css and swipper.js files. This plugin works in the normal HTML file. The swiper.slideNext() is not working when I am using in angular js controller file.

Comment: kindly check out https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular-swiper for angular equivalent directive for swiper.js

Comment: Can't we use  this plugin: http://idangero.us/swiper in angular js

Comment: @harish-s to use jquery plugin in angular application, best way is to create directive to wrap that jquery plugin code. https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular-swiper this guy is already developed directive for us to use in angular way. Its using same plugin that you have mentioned, he have added directive wrapper to use it in angular. Give it a try , this is the only best way to use jquery in angular

Comment: Where is angular included in you dom?
It should be after including the swiper.js, That's the only issue. I have used several java-script libraries in similar pattern with  angular

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the plugin code in angular directive. 
please refer following links to implement the desired functionality

- [UI-Swiper](http://nebulr.github.io/ui-swiper/)
- [Angular Swiper](https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular-swiper)

Please refer above links to integrate the swiper.js in you application in angular way

Answer (score 0):

```html
     <!-- Swiper -->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="monitor">
<div ng-controller="appController" >
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2
            <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
<div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('monitor', []);
app.controller('appController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true

    });
 
 console.log('in1');

    $scope.next = function() {
  console.log('in2');
        $scope.swiper.slideNext();
  console.log('out');
    }

});

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: works as expected! :) Even using var, instead of $scope will work